# Metodo para crear una variable consecutiva que sea la base para asignar un folio

Tags: java

En mi proyecto me piden que cada que se de de alta un Boleto este tenga un folio que sea 0001, luego 0002 y asi sucesivamente pero que este no se reinicie cada que se cierra y abre el programa, trate de hacerlo con un archivo binario pero la primera vez que corro el programa me marca un error, esto solo en la variable de clase que uso como consecutivo pues también uso archivos binarios para que no se reinicien mis arreglos y no me salta este error con ellos al iniciar por primera vez.
Esto es lo que uso para cargar mis datos al abrir el programa, el "ManipulaArchivos" es una clase que hice para cargar y guardar binarios.

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)                                  
{                                      
    a = (Avion[]) ManipulaArchivos.carga("Aviones.dat");
    r = (Rutas[]) ManipulaArchivos.carga("Rutas.dat");
    b = (Boletos[]) ManipulaArchivos.carga("Boletos.dat");
    Boletos.setConsecutivo((int) ManipulaArchivos.carga("Consecutivo.dat"));
}                                 

private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)                                   
{                                       
    ManipulaArchivos.guarda("Aviones.dat", a);
    ManipulaArchivos.guarda("Rutas.dat", r);
    ManipulaArchivos.guarda("Boletos.dat", b);
    ManipulaArchivos.guarda("Consecutivo.dat", Boletos.getConsecutivo());
}
```

El problema esta en el consecutivo pues al ser un entero necesito que inicie en 1 para poder usarlo, no es necesario usar un archivo binario para este pero creí que asi sería más fácil y resultó que no, entonces necesito algún método para poder solucionar esto, ya sea con archivos binarios o no, sólo necesito que el consecutivo aumente en cada nueva alta y no se reinicie cada que abro el programa de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, por favor agregar el código donde utilizas el contador y también el código que manipula archivos.
Por lo que entiendo, tu enfoque parece correcto. Ya que para que no se pierda el valor de tu contador debes persistirlo en un medio no volátil, como lo es la memoria RAM en donde se ejecuta tu programa.  Para ello puedes optar por un archivo (sería lo más simple) o también puedes usar una base de datos para mantener ese valor (Un poco mas complejo).
Respecto a tu problema, es dificil saber que error tienes si no agregas dicho error a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Publica el código de la clase **ManipulaArchivos** o el método que lee el archivo.
Y aclará si el contador es una variable estática de la clase Boletos y como se asigna su valor??

El problema parece estar en la asignación del valor en la variable estática que funciona como contador. Si es la primera ejecución del programa, debe tener en cuenta si existe el archivo o no.